# How to make youtrack not show solved issues

Tags: youtrack

I am trying to figure out how to make Youtrack not show the resolved issues. It doesn't make sense. Is there an option to disable this by default?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think the answer is that if you don't want to show resolved issues, you have to manually incorporate this in your search terms (include *#unresolved* or whatever works for your situation). You can of course save searches, and bookmark searches. But I haven't found a way to, by default, include *#unresolved* in all searches.

Comment: It's really strange that's resolved issues are shown by default, really annoying

Comment: On general note, the syntax for negation in youtrack issue search is `-Resolved` which is exactly the same as `#Unresolved`. Common mistake is negating the search query including the hash character `-#Resolved` which yields error.

Comment: I really don't like this behavior, so I posted this: https://youtrack-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000380590-Show-only-unresolved-issue-by-default

Answer (score 3):

Our team is new to YouTrack, but in the current cloud version I found a way to do this.  I'm assuming you are referring to the /issues page.

1. Create a saved search for unresolved issues - "Unresolved"
2. Update the dropdown to the right of the search bar from "Everything" to your saved search "Unresolved"
3. Reload the page and it defaults to "Unresolved."  Whoo hoo!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a trick which needs nginx or something to proxy YouTrack.
Add `-Djetbrains.youtrack.baseUrl=http://127.0.0.1:PORT1` to the wrapper.conf file.
Then make nginx automatically change `/issues` queries for you.

```
server {
listen PORT2;
server_name IP_FQDN;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

location / {   
    proxy_pass http://localhost:PORT1;
    client_max_body_size 10m;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    }

location /issues {
    if ($args ~* (.*)(q=)(.*)) {
    set $first_part $1;
    set $last_part $3;
    }
    if ($last_part !~ "(.*)(Unresolved)(.*)") {
    set $args "${first_part}q=%23Unresolved%20${last_part}";
    }
    if ($args = ""){
      rewrite ^/issues /issues?q=%23Unresolved break;
    }
    proxy_pass http://localhost:PORT1;
    client_max_body_size 10m;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    }

location /api/eventSourceBus {
    proxy_cache off;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_read_timeout 86400s;
    proxy_send_timeout 86400s;
    proxy_set_header Connection '';
    chunked_transfer_encoding off;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host; 
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; 
    proxy_http_version 1.1;  
    proxy_pass http://localhost:PORT1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just use "for: me -Resolved", that shows all the unresolved tickets that are assigned to my user profile